# High temperatures dual AMD GPU Llano

Tags: power-management, ati, overheating, temperature

i got a problem.

I tried a lot of distributions (ubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu, kubuntu too) and i've the same problem on everyone of them:

I always have high temperatures caused (i think) by dual GPU system.

Here's my config:

CPU:Amd llano 3510mx
GPU1(internal): AMD 6620G 512MB
GPU2(External): AMD 66470 1GB DDR3
RAM: 4gb 1333Mhz DDR3

I tried both fglrx and radeon open source drivers with the following results:

Radeon results: 90° Idle - Shutdown after 10 mins caused by high temperatures.
Fglrx results: 60-70° Idle - 75 - 80° With gnome 3 animations. If i try to watch a video the system shutdown.

On windows i've 65° with Max performance, youtube video and eclipse running. and 45°
on Idle.

So, how can i solve this problem?

PS: I CAN'T shutdown internal gpu from bios...

I've to recompile kernel in any way?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sounds like the driver or graphics card has an issue with power management in conjunction with bad cooling. You probably want to search for a driver update that fixes power management. I would recommend the closed source drivers, they are often the first to fix cooling related issues.

Comment: chk this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Answer (score 0):

Overheating can be caused by inadequate ventilation (add an external fan), dirty and blocked air vents (clean thee hardware) and running a lot of programs at the same time. This can effect your battery, lead to shut downs, cause laptop to behave erratically, and eventually your laptop failing.

Comment: Ventilation is good. i said i've -25° on Windows. So Ubuntu(Linux kernel or drivers) are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's all related to graphic card. Check [the page that Web-E linked](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics).